# turn page based on js using urllib

Tags: python, pagination, urllib, scraper

I want to scrap a website articles but the problem is that there is a lot of articles organized by pages from 1 to 10.
The page number is not defined as parameter in the url, and its controled by a js function:

```
javascript:MovePage(2+1)
```

Is it possible to do that using urllib or any other console library on python ?

Comment: The short answer is no because you need the javascript to be run in a browser engine like WebKit. So the solution will likely be to use something like selenium. What platform are you trying to run you python script on?

Comment: morph.io i don't think selenium will work on it :/